# Campo duplicado ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, mvc, asp.net-core, identity, validation

Bom dia estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação WEB e na parte de cadastro pesso um campo de CPF mas como ele nao pode ser igual ao que existe no banco ele da erro, eu queria que retornasse uma menssagem de erro na VIEW e nao retornasse uma pagina de erro como abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu implementei o Remote validation mas nao esta funcionando, como eu implemento esse validation?

RegistroVireModel:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} é obrigatorio")]
[Remote("CPFExiste", "Usuario", AdditionalFields = "Id")]
public string CPF { get; set; }
```

UsuarioController:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> CPFExiste(string cpf, string Id)

{

if (Id == null) // novo registro

{

if (await _contexto.Usuarios.AnyAsync(x => x.CPF == cpf))

return Json("Exercício já existe");

return Json(true);

}

else // atualização de registro

{

if (await _contexto.Usuarios.AnyAsync(x => x.CPF == cpf && x.Id != Id))

return Json("Exercício já existe");

return Json(true);

}
```

Registro.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: O que acontece? Se tem dois return, porque???

Comment: Entao, o atual erro é esse da imagen, retorna a pagina de erro, oque eu queria é retornar uma menssagem de erro na propria view de registro, exemplo, no topo da pagina de registro "CPF ja em uso", eu pedi a ajuda para um professor e ele me passou esse codigo, nao sei mt bem o motivo dos dois returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, verifique na classe Startup.cs para onde está direcionando os erros:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
  app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
  app.UseHsts();
}
```

Caso esteja assim use o `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");` para desenvolvimento e verá uma página personalizada ao invés desse página de exceção.

Você também pode usar o TempData caso queira exibir apenas um aviso na própria View em que está, na controller:

```
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {

     if (await _contexto.Usuarios.AnyAsync(x => x.CPF == cpf))
     {
       ModelState.Clear();
       TempData["erro"] = "Já existe um usuário com o mesmo CPF!";
       return View();
     }

     TempData["sucesso"] = "Usuário adicionado!";
     return Json(true);

  }
```

Na View:

```
<h4>@TempData["erro"]</h4>
<h4>@TempData["sucesso"]</h4>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!

Comment: Show @GabrielRodriguesPavolin sucesso cara!!!